# Catching exceptions inflating layouts

Tags: android, layout, exception, inflate

I am trying to inflate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Item  android:id="@+id/ltArr"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/ImText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ltArr"/>
<Item  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ImText"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In a procedure I am calling addTextView, and it is in a try catch block

```
try{
    addTextView("Showtext", intID, addtothisLayout);
    }catch (Exception ex){}
```

When inflating the layout above in the addText procedure there is a exception which is caught above, execution gets sent back to the catch in the calling procedure

```
void addTextView(String showTxt,integer id,  ViewGroup addtoparent)
{
View itemview = View.inflate(this, R.layout.itemlayout, addtoparent); //this causes the exception
..
..
}
```

Why when the exception is thrown can I not see anything in the ex variable?

Am I trying something silly ?

How do I see what the exception says? I have tried inspecting the exception ex variable as teh debugger passes over it but it does not have anything in it. If I was using a SQL in the procedure. I'd specifically throw SQLException and that would allow me to see the error description but here I dont know what to throw ... ?

I've found reference to a resource not available exception in LogCat by removing the try catch clauses. But how do I catch those descriptions in the try ex var? Do I have to throw specific exceptions?

OK this is my answer, I was trying to inspect the declaration of the variable and needed to put something in the code block. "ex.toString()"

```
catch (Exception ex){
            ex.toString();
        }
```

Thank all for the very prompt replies.

Comment: The relative layout lacks his closing '>'

Comment: "throwing an exception": there is [Logcat](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) and if you append the error to your question it should be possible to find an answer.

Comment: hint: `catch (Exception ex){ Log.e("TAG", "Error!", ex); }` will print the message to logcat. If you catch it and just convert it to a String it will be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run it on an AVD 2.3.3 emulator I'm getting:

```
04-28 22:03:36.537: E/AndroidRuntime(395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.android.tests/com.android.tests.TestsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class Item
```

That is, "Item" is not recognized as a view.

Comment: Also note, the TextView lacks `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, both are required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inflate the entire layout, not just a view within it, you must use:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(...
```

getLayoutInflater() is an Activity's method

Comment: catch (Exception ex){
 ex.toString();
  }